# Step animation not working with velocity progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, velocity.js

When I know the power of velocity. I wan't convert all my CSS3 animation on my apps using velocity. And now I have problem with step animation.

**This is the snippet**

```js
$el = $(".velocity-animation");

$el.velocity({
 paddingLeft : "0"
}, {
  duration: 3000,
    easing : "ease",
   progress: function(elements, complete) {
     var step = complete * 100 ;
     if(step <= 50 ){
        $el.velocity({
           paddingLeft : "50px"
          })
      } else if(step <= 70 ){
       $el.velocity({
           paddingLeft : "0px"
         })
      } else if(step <= 100 ){
       $el.velocity({
           paddingLeft : "300px"
         })
      }
    }
})
```

```css
.css-animation, .velocity-animation {
  background : red;
}

.css-animation {
  animation : 3s move;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    padding-left:0;
  }
  50% {
    padding-left:50px;
  }
  70% {
    padding-left:0;
  }
  100% {
    padding-left:300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="css-animation">
  Animate it
</div>

<div class="velocity-animation">
  Animate It
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.4.1/velocity.min.js"></script>
```

And here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nLx3z32z/

Comment: If you want the velocity to change perhaps you want to use an easing function?: http://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67

Comment: More than that, I want velocity run step animation, like css3 does. (on 30%, 70%, 100%)

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Velocity.RunSequence(mySequence);
```

to run step animation (animation in sequence).

Example:

```
var animationSequence = [
    { e: $("#yourElm"), p: { translateX: 0 } , o: duration: 300 },
    { e: $("#yourElm"), p: { translateX: 100, opacity: 0 } , o: duration: 300 },
    { e: $("#yourElm"), p: { translateY: 100, rotateZ: 45 } , o: duration: 150 }
];
 $.Velocity.RunSequence(animationSequence);
```